# size of an array with template

Tags: c++, c++11

Why we need a template for calculating the size of an array why cant i calculate directly with predefined datatypes like int

I have seen the code like

```
template<typename T,int SIZE>
size_t array_size(const T (&array)[SIZE])
{

    return SIZE;
}
```

instead of template if we are directly using int why its throwing error

```
int N;
int size(int (&arr1)[N]) //Passing the array by reference 
{
     return N; //Correctly returns the size too [cool trick ;-)]
}
```

how its calculating the size

Comment: Don't spam tags.  This has nothing to do with C.  It's pure C++.

Comment: It's interesting. But you can't assign a value to `N` this way.

Comment: Array dimension must be compile time constant in C++.

Answer (score 5):

The size of an array is part of its type.  When you create an array like

```
int array[5]{};
```

then its type is actually `int[5]`, not `int[]` or `int*`.  That means when you do

```
template<typename T,int SIZE>
size_t array_size(const T (&array)[SIZE])
{

    return SIZE;
}
```

and you pass, for example `array`, the compiler deduces `T` and `SIZE` from `int[5]` and you get `int` and `5` respectively.

```
int N;
int size(int (&arr1)[N]) //Passing the array by reference 
{
     return N; //Correctly returns the size too [cool trick ;-)]
}
```

on the other hand does not do that same thing.  This declares a function that takes an array of size `N`, but since `N` is not a constant expression it won't even compile.  Even if you have a non-standard extension (like gcc's VLA extension) then `N` will never change and the code still won't compile.  Even if it were to compile, `N` never changes so the function would always return the same result no matter what size array is passed.

Comment: if this is the case, then why size_t array_size(int (&array)[SIZE]) is giving error

Comment: What error are you getting?  The forst example works just fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc30211f5993bed)